# Refreshing a particular div with reloading the whole page in php

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, codeigniter

I need to reload a particular div without reloading the whole page.

```
<div class="">
                        <div class="contactpagecaptchas">
                            <img src="/captcha.php?rand=<?php echo rand();?>" class="contactpagecaptchass" id='captchaimg'/>
                            <p class="change"><a href="javascript: refreshCaptcha();" class="clickto">Click to change</a></p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="contactcaptcha">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha" placeholder="Captcha" style="background-color: #f4f4f4;border: none;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Once i click on refresh captcha text box should get cleared.

Comment: Preform an `ajax` call to your server side `php` method..

Comment: actually i tried with some code but not working

Comment: Could you please show what you've tried?

Comment: If i enter the captcha text in the div and refresh the captcha then the div should get cleared

Comment: What u have tried.You should post your ajax code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.clickto').click(function() {
  $('[name="captcha"]').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
  <div class="contactpagecaptchas">
    <img src="/captcha.php?rand=<?php echo rand();?>" class="contactpagecaptchass" id='captchaimg' />
    <p class="change"><a href="#" class="clickto">Click to change</a></p>
  </div>

  <div class="contactcaptcha">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha" placeholder="Captcha" style="background-color: #f4f4f4;border: none;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try onclick method of javascript

```
<div id="abc" ><?php echo rand(); ?></div>
<button onclick="refcaptcha()" >
<script>
function refcaptcha(){
    var x = document.getElementById("abc")
    x.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1);
    //if you want to clear the captcha code than assign '' to that id
    //x.innerHTML = '';
}
</script>
```